Do I need to distinguish between true and apparent solar zenith angles in PVLib?
I wish to estimate DHI and DNI from GHI using pvlib.irradiance.erbs. I first compute solar positions at the location in question using pvlib.Location.get_solarposition. Then I use the zenith angles and weather data GHI with erbs. Afterwards I adjust for solar tracking with pvlib.tracking.singleaxis and finally compute irradiance with pvlib.irradiance.get_total_irradiance.
I notice that pvlib.tracking.singleaxis and pvlib.irradiance.get_total_irradiance take apparent solar angles, pvlib.irradiance.erbs takes true zenith angle, while pvlib.Location.get_solarposition does not specify which kind.
This makes me wonder if, and how, I should correct for apparent vs true solar angle between these functions? And if so, which kind should I use with pvlib.Location.get_solarposition?

The apparent zenith angle calculation takes into account the refraction or bending of the beam of light from the sun as it travels through earth's atmosphere.  The "true" zenith angle is accurate at the top of the atmosphere, and would also be accurate at ground level if there were no atmosphere. However, in terrestrial applications, the apparent zenith angle is the more accurate one.  It is the one that should be used as input to most pvlib functions for simulating PV systems, unless otherwise specified.
The reason why a function/model like Erbs requires "true" zenith angle is that it has empirical constants whose values were determined in the past using "true" zenith angle as input.
The solar position functions give you both angles, so you can use the appropriate one in the appropriate place.  Nevertheless, you could just use the apparent zenith angle everywhere and not worry about it!
